# svn upgrade to 1.8 , will make it unusable for older clients

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

After installing new windows, and install the latest svn and Tortois , when try to update my working copy it give me warning that I shoul

d upgrade first , but if click on upgrade I will get this message 
[image]

what does it mean that it will be unusable for older clients , will it affect the main repository , or it's just locally and I can update and commit normally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just locally as the message stayed "This will upgrade **your working copy**". But than all your local SVN-Clients have to be 1.8 compatible.

In our project we have also a mixed client-infrastructure - some use 1.8 clients some 1.7 and it works fine.

If you are still not sure do the upgrade an open commit dialog -> you will see what (not) have be changed.